# Hyper-V Guests Dying

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I just hit my THIRD instance of a Hyper-V guest machine dying with the exact same behavior.  In all three instances we are hosting WS2008 guests on a WS2008 host.  AFter a config change, we reboot the guest and the guest OS comes up but in a very cripled state.  Specifically, we are able to log into the guest, but can't launch any apps and the guest never comes active on the network.

I opened a support ticket with MS the second time this happened and they focused in on the DCOM subsystem not coming up...best explanation they could provide was that permissions on key system files got corrupted.  I eventually gave up on the ticket after close to 10 hours on the phone trying different things that were going no where.

What really concerns me is that we have now seen the exact same thing happen to a guest hosted on a completly differet host machine.  There is zero hardware overlap between the two.

Has anyone seen this before??  It's really odd behavior, 
but it also seems like there's a pattern here that's concerning me.

Thanks,
jon

Comment: What is the config change you made before you rebooted the guest?  Was it working just fine before you made the change?

Comment: I would start looking at common software or configurations between your guests.  Maybe it is not a Hyper-V issue.

Comment: Also, what kind of storage?  Is this local disk or a SAN of some kind?  Could you be having disk issues that is corrupting the images?

Comment: The config change has been different all three times...one was applying a CRM update, one was completing OCS install, other was adding a CPU.

Comment: On one host, the guest was running on a local RAID array, on the other it was on an attached SAN drive.  The hosts are totally seperate, one is here in our office one is in our data center.

Comment: Just curious if you have upgraded/migrated to R2 now that RTM is released and what services were you running on the guests?

Comment: Can you also update with what OS you are running on your guests as it sounds like the parent partition is not having any issues at all. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: I think you should reopen the call with MS and get it escalated. Was this through Premier Support? If so then contact your TAM and get them to look into it as you may have been stuck with just the first level of support and not talking to the right people.

Answer (score 1):

Any antivirus on the host OS? AV software with "live scanning" can cause problems but I'd imagine you'd have found that quicker as it's quite a known thing.

Answer (score 0):

erm. Just checking....but the servers have been activated, right?

Comment: Yep...servers were fully activated.